# How to copy error message(s) from RStudio RMarkdown console?

Tags: rstudio

I want to copy the error message :

[image]

It was highlighted and I right clicked but "copy" is not available:

[image]

In any case i did try command-C (i'm on mac) but it did not copy to the clipboard.   So how to copy the message(s) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on `Output` on the top right of the display, and you'll get the log of the run from which this message was extracted.  You can do normal copying there.